# XAMPP is removing HTTP headers with underscores

Tags: php, http, http-headers, xampp

I'm trying to get a PHP application to run that relies on a specific browser that supplies additional information via HTTP headers. Specifically, it is the EVE Online ingame browser, but my problem lies in the way XAMPP (specifically XAMPP USB Lite 1.8.0) handles those headers.

What I observed is that the specific header I need (`HTTP_EVE_TRUSTED`) is not available in `$_SERVER` when I try it with XAMPP on Windows, but it is there if I use an Apache installation on Debian.

I used a simple script to output the headers:

```
<?php 
print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

and only this one header is missing when the script is hosted on XAMPP. I suspect that XAMPP has some strange default configuration that strips certain headers, maybe a security feature, but I can't find anything about that.

On suggestion from Nacerridine I used Tamper Data for Firefox to reproduce the issue and I found that only headers containing underscores are removed.

What could cause this header to be unavailable on XAMPP but not on other servers? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried sending this same header using another tool (something like [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) on Firefox) ? I tried reproducing the issue (using tamper data) and the header is still there (XAMPP v1.7.7).

Comment: @Nacereddine I just downloaded Tamper Data and reproduced the issue, when I add the header to the request to XAMPP it doesn't appear, when I do the same for the request to my Apache on Debian the header is present.

Comment: What version of XAMPP are you using ?

Comment: Your try in an "minimal script",  could be a problem in your code?

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find the exact reason why the header was being removed from the `$_SERVER` array, but you can still access the the same information using [`apache_request_headers`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

```
$requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();
if ($requestHeaders){
    echo $requestHeaders['EVE_TRUSTED'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having same problem, I am passing Custom header variable using cUrl but when i am printing $_SERVER variable, i couldn't see custom header variable..

but when i print

```
apache_request_headers()
```

custom variable is available.

let me know if you have reconfigured your server to get this done. I am using xampp 1.8.0